# C++ member function with auto and default arguments

Tags: c++, class, lambda

I am trying to implement a member function in a C++ class which has an auto argument (a lambda) and an int argument with a default value. Something like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    int add_one(auto fobj, int b=3);
};

int Base::add_one(auto add_fcn, int b) {
    return add_fcn(1, b);
}
```

However, a simple test like this fails to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int add_one(auto fobj, int b=3);
};

int Base::add_one(auto add_fcn, int b) {
    return add_fcn(1, b);
}

int main() {
    int ans;
    auto add_fcn = [](int a, int b) -> int {return a + b;};
    Base obj;
    ans = obj.add_one(add_fcn);
    std::cout << ans << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The error the compiler (MinGW 7.2.0, flags: -std=c++14) gives me is the following:

```
error: call to 'int Base::add_one(auto:2, int) [with auto:1 = main()::<lambda(int, int)>]' uses the default argument for parameter 2, which is not yet defined
```

I sincerely do not understand the error. Can someone please explain me the reason of this error and how it can be fixed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: You are relying on a GNU extension here

Comment: It's the worst use of `auto`. Don't use it as a function's argument.

Comment: Your compiler should have said something like [error: ISO C++ forbids use of 'auto' in parameter declaration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59aeb3baec4fb00b). Do you want to use standard C++ or are you willing to use non-standard extensions?

Comment: I am sincerely sorry. @Someprogrammerdude I have updated the example.

Comment: @Raindrop7, would you mind briefly explaining (or referring to) an alternative?

Comment: @nwp I am using c++14, and I do not want to use anything more.

Comment: If you want C++14 and no more, add the `-pedantic-errors` flag to your build commands. It checks for *a bit* more than merely making the compiler follow the standard to the letter, but it's generally good.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`auto` parameters is a *gcc* extension. It means that it is not a standard compliant way to solve the problem.

I am not sure what is the exact reason for the error above, but you might achieve the same effect with template member function which works well:

```
class Base {
public:
    template<typename F>
    int add_one(F fobj, int b = 3);
};

template<typename F>
int Base::add_one(F add_fcn, int b) {
    return add_fcn(1, b);
}
```

[**Wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rHFvwUOPt0NTZBmK)

Another possible way is to use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (which implies some performance overhead though):

```
class Base {
public:
    int add_one(std::function<int(int, int)> fobj, int b = 3);
};

int Base::add_one(std::function<int(int, int)> add_fcn, int b) {
    return add_fcn(1, b);
}
```

[**Wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bzgryQxwWJ1pV1il)

Finally, you could make use of pointers to functions, but it is too *C* way...

---

If you'd like to expand your knowledge on passing functions to functions, [this article](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html) by Vittorio Romeo gives an excellent explanation + some benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using function pointers as they explicitly define the expected signature.